# Customisation in FScalendar view?

Tags: ios, fscalendar

**Is it possible to do this kind of customization in FSCalender View as below image?**

[image: FSCalender View]

FSCalender provides us round circle layout on the selection of date which is in left.

but

I need the layout like right end side when selecting a date it also selects the day of that date with square border.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you can find how to make the shape a rectangle:
https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/MOREUSAGE.md#the-day-shape-doesnt-have-to-be-a-circle

There are more properties to change apprearance declared here:
https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/FSCalendar/FSCalendarAppearance.h

Especially  `borderSelectionColor` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for the response but I want this kind of border which is in below image

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB5ej.png

Answer (score -1):

yes you can add custom image in FSCalendar

Comment: please try to understand my question. I don't want to add an image in FSCalendar